# Using Remote Desktop to access Windows 10 VM causes it to lock-up

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have a windows 10 host running hyper-v. It has a VM also running windows 10.
If I use remote desktop services to log in to the VM, almost immediately after providing password and hitting enter, the entire VM becomes unresponsive. 
I might see the status circle dots spin a couple of times but then stop.

I check hyper-v manager and it looks pegged at 16% (there are two virtual processors) - not sure if it is significant.

I attempt to use Hyper-V manager to Connect to the VM, but it can't connect.

I'm not sure where to look for errors. The event viewer on the VM didn't seem to have anything useful.

I end up having to switch the VM off and on again.

Any ideas to fix / trouble-shoot would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question to [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0239628c-ff46-46ef-8733-fdaa16609ca7/windows-10-vm-is-locking-up-after-entering-credentials-on-welcome-screen?forum=win10itpronetworking&prof=required) and thanks to some posts and my own investigations I found the following workarounds:

1. **If you want to use Remote Desktop and save the password**: Disabling "Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections" group policy setting appears to be a successful workaround when you have saved credentials for the connection / rdp file.
   See mid-way down on [this page](https://borncity.com/win/2019/08/28/windows-10-v1903-rdp-dwm-exe-causes-high-cpu-load-freezes-vms/)
2. **If you want to use Remote Desktop but don't want to change group policy**: Save an rdp file for the RDS and tick the checkbox to always ask for credentials.
3. **Use the Hyper-V manager's Connect action**.